# Error Displaying Multiple Fields

Tags: php, database, loops, rows

please help me on this, i am a beginner. I need to display multiple fields from my database. But somehow, this code only display the first row.

```
 if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
$output .= "<p>Table: $tbl</p><p>";
// BUG - SHOULD LOOP THRU MULTIPLE rows
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$i = 0;
while ($i < mysql_num_fields($result)) 
{
    //echo "Information for column $i:<br />\n";
    $fieldN = mysql_field_name($result, $i);
    if (!$fieldN) {   $output .= "No info available<br />\n";  }
    if ($row[$i]) {
        $fieldN = mysql_field_name($result, $i);
        if (!$fieldN) {   $fieldN = "No_field_name";  }
        $output .= " $tbl F: $fieldN  V: $row[$i]<br />\n";
    }
    $i++;
 } // end while
  $output .= "</p>";
}  // end if number of rows > 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are fetching result with `$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);` which returns only a single row from a recordset as a numeric array.

Inorder to get all records in the resultset, you have to fetch each records from the resultset using `$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);`

Try with code:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))    //  while there are results
{
  // get each field values inside this loop
}
```

Comment: I am using option/dropdown form to choose the table which i want to display, the field values are different in each table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
```

instead of

```
while ($i < mysql_num_fields($result))
```

mysqli_fetch_array() allows you to fetch data as a numeric array and as an associative array.

If you have a database field called ID which is on the first row of the database table, you can use something like this:

```
$id = $row[0];
$id = $row['ID'];
```

as compared to fetch_row and fetch_assoc which can only fetch on what they could (numeric array and associative array respectively).

Comment: Actually I am using option/dropdown form to choose the table which i want to display, the field values are different in each table.

Comment: Yes. It can be done with this. All you have to do is to query the database based on the value which you are comparing with and run the while loop. What it does is it loops through every single row found in the database that satisfies your requirement (in this case, the name of the table).

Answer (score 0):

```
// LOOP THRU MULTIPLE rows
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))  {
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < mysql_num_fields($result)) {
        //echo "Information for column $i:<br />\n";
        if ($row[$i]) {
            $fieldN = mysql_field_name($result, $i);
            if (!$fieldN) {    $fieldN = "No_field_name";  }
            $output .= " $tbl F: $fieldN  V: $row[$i]<br />\n";
        }
        $i++;
    } // end while loop thru fields in each row
    $output .= "</p>";
    } // end while there is a row
```